# curl_exec always returns 0?

Tags: php, session, cookies, curl

I have this function:

```
function Connect($url, $post = 0, $postfields = '') 
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    if($post > 0) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
    } 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__).'/joomla-cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__).'/joomla-cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    $exec = curl_exec($ch);
    if($exec) { return $exec; } else { return 0; }
}
```

I call it like that `Connect($host)`

And it always return 0...

Comment: `$host` suggests you are sending "google.com" , where as the url needed is `http://google.com`, what are you using?

Comment: @Sabeen i acctually sending it with the https://
Maybe it's cuz https:// and not http:// ?
cuz "http://www.google.com" works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER and CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST to false. that should do the trick.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
```

Comment: @Sabeen There is a way to enable the cookie to support SSL too?
Cuz the session only saves when im using http:// ...

Comment: I don't think the https should effect the way cookies are stored. Look at the joomla-cookie.txt file to see what it contains, that might give u some clues.

Comment: @Sabeen Yup i dont think it should effect it also, but it does lol.
I have no clue in cookies.. Here is the pastebin: http://pastebin.com/RX9vnEbT

Comment: Are you moving between http and https?

Comment: @Sabeen I think so, not sure though.

Comment: try to make sure that you start with https and submit to https. I believe if you will cross over between https and http, you will loose the cookie. Also is the domain the same for https as well. sometimes sites have https://secure.domain.com etc

Comment: Please note that [disabling VERIFYPEER or VERIFYHOST makes the connection vulnerable to MITM attacks](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13742121/372643).

Answer (score 1):

Check if there was an error with the request after curl_exec:

```
if(curl_errno($ch)){
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
```

That will provide you with enough info to know if there was a error with the request. If there was no error, you can check the request sent after curl_exec so you can double check that everything sent is in place:

```
print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
```

Comment: Thank You ! i get SSL error:
Curl error: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Detai
ls:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify faile
dSession ID:
Curl error: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

So it must be because of the https://..