# Alternative for using CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2

Tags: php, ssl, curl, authorize.net

I am using the auth.net XML class written by John Conde, http://www.johnconde.net/blog/tutorial-integrate-authorize-net-xml-api-universal-php-class/,. In it it has two lines.

```
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/ssl/cert.pem');
```

Can I replace this with

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_CAINFO, NULL);
curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_CAPATH, NULL);
```

I might not be able to get the .pem file, or info I need to create it. Would this alternative be just as secure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would this alternative be just as secure?

No, disabling `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` or `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` would allow for possible MITM attacks (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13742121/372643)).

> I might not be able to get the .pem file, or info I need to create it

The info you need to create it is ultimately a judgement call from you, choosing which CAs you want to trust. Browsers and OSes tend to make a pre-selection for you. Curl [comes with a convenient script and CA bundle using the Firefox CA selection](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html) (this selection is updated once in a while). Some Linux distributions also provide a default CA bundle file that you may be able to use.

Comment: Thanks for this info. I completely misunderstood when doing my research. I though I had to make a .pem file using my existing certificates. Now that you told me this I will use the Firefox CA bundle. Thanks again for the info.