# How to enable CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST = 2 support on my OS/PHP

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I have been developing a site locally that authenticates against a centrailzed signon.  One of the steps is requiring me to make a curl request to an https resource to get an access token.

Part of the curl config is:

```
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);                                         
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
```

As you can see I commented out the CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST option.  I have read on php.net and on various blogs/stackoverflow ([Security consequences of disabling CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST (libcurl/openssl)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13740933/security-consequences-of-disabling-curlopt-ssl-verifyhost-libcurl-openssl)) posts WHAT these options mean.

On my development machine `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST 2` has been working fine.  I am just using the vanilla php install provided in ubuntu 12.04 php5 package, and php5-curl.

On production (rackspace cloudsites) the `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST 2` is not working, which is why I changed it to false to verify this was the issue. Seeing as i didn't explicitly do anything to enable this on my localhost I do not know what directives/config options controls this.

What I mean by it is "not working" is that on production the curl call is returning an `http_code` of `0` when the `VERIFYHOST` is set to `2`.  When I set it to `FALSE` it is returning a status code of `200`

My question is:

**How can i enable `SSL_VERIFYHOST` on a linux box?**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: curl's default is `2` for this setting: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For '2' you have to ensure the common name in the SSL certificate matches the hostname being utilized. This is the default and should be straight-forward as long as your SSL certificate is appropriately created for the hostname (common name) you're using it on.

From the PHP curl_setopt manual:

> 1 to check the existence of a common name in the SSL peer certificate. 2 to check the existence of a common name and also verify that it matches the hostname provided. In production environments the value of this option should be kept at 2 (default value).

[Manual Entry for curl_setopt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)