# cURL curl_exec request is failing

Tags: php, curl, google-font-api

I'm creating a PHP-based Google Webfont API for a project and other developers to use. This script is almost one with the exception of a single method that is causing me grief.

#### The issue:

I have a method that uses cURL to *replace* the existing JSON string with a current copy from Google.

```
public function refreshFontList() {
    if(empty($this->publicKey)) {
        throw new Exception("API key cannot be empty", 1);
    }

    // cURL support is needed, test for cURL support before firing
    if(!in_array("curl", get_loaded_extensions())) {
        if(!init_get("allow_url_fopen")) {
            die("Cannot get remote file");
        }
    } else {
        echo "From Google\n";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
                CURLOPT_URL             => "https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=" . $this->publicKey,
                CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER  => TRUE, // for < PHP 5.1.3
                CURLOPT_FAILONERROR     => TRUE,
                CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT   => TRUE,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => TRUE,
                CURLOPT_HEADER          => FALSE
            )
        );
        var_dump(curl_exec($ch)); // shows as FALSE
        curl_close($ch);
    }
}
```

For some reason unknown to me, the `ch_exec()` function fails to capture the output of the API call to Google and simply prints `boolean(false)` as the output. To better understand the scope of the project, here is the class in its entirety: http://tny.cz/d894e185.

#### What I've Tried

```
...
$output = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($output);      // still false
...
```

and

```
$this->setFontList(ch_exec($ch));
```

Additionally, I have also disabled all of the options I set for `curl_setopt_array` with no avail.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check (and add to question) [`curl_error($ch)`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php).

Comment: @djthoms Did you try `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => FALSE, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,` ?

Comment: @Jonny5 that worked! Brilliant I say! Write that in an answer so I can give you credit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it with:

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => FALSE,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,
```

Further information:

[CURLOPTSSLVERIFYHOST](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTSSLVERIFYHOST) [CURLOPTSSLVERIFYPEER](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTSSLVERIFYPEER)

Comment: Please note that [disabling VERIFYPEER or VERIFYHOST makes the connection vulnerable to MITM attacks](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13742121/372643).